# I was recording and video on my phone when the battery died, how can I recover the video file?

Tags: data-recovery, video, htc, video-recording, htc-evo-3d

I read the other questions I could find. This is completely different. My question is **NOT about finding the file**.

**The file is on my phone**. It is the correct size. It shows as an mp4 with the right icon on windows. It has an mp4 suffix. It's 22+MB so it's there. It will not play in MS Media Player or with VLC player. It doesn't show up on the phone itself in the gallery, but it's there when I connect the phone to my laptop.

I was recording the video, my battery died, the phone shut off while I was recording.

There are many programs on the internet that claim to fix video files, but I'm afraid to download any of them because I do not want to get a virus.

My phone is an HTC EVO 3D. My carrier is Sprint. My laptop is a Samsung running Windows 7. I recorded it regular mode not in 3D mode.

How do I **play** this file? How do I **fix it**? What should I do? If there's a piece of software I should download to my laptop to fix it, what is a good reputable site where I won't get malware/virus?

Comment: About the malware(virus) part, you can use VMware/VirtualBox to contain the software in an isolated environment. Then download anything in it from any site and test it on a copy of video file. No worries; I use it a lot. // Does the file show up in [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en)? Could it be possible to share this video file if there are no privacy concerns?

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the quick response. I didn't know about those pieces of software to create a virtual space. Where can i download a copy and not have to worry about malware/virus/etc.? What is MX Player? I've never heard of it. I've actually got a bunch of other files like this, but I never could figure out why they were "corrupted"(for lack of a better word). I'm not sure which are of more of a "private" nature, lol. Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)(Free) or [Vmware Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/7_0)(You may use the [Workstation](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/workstation-evaluation?productId=462&rPId=7456) as well.). MX Player is a powerful media player for Android. I suggested it in hopes that it might be able to decode  and play the file somehow.

Comment: @Firelord My phone is such a piece of garbage, lol. I wouldn't dare install anything on it. I took it to sprint and they said it couldn't be fixed. This is my 4th one, mind you, and I got this phone the day it came out in 2011. I've had a free upgrade due me for two years but just nevered bothered cause I didn't like the new phones. They said this one couldn't be fixed and offered me a new model free phone, but I told them I couldn't just leave it with them as I needed my data. They told me I couldn't get it off cause the port was bad, but I told them I could connect it to laptop still -cont'd

Comment: Also, [SU] has lots of questions related to Virtualbox and Vmware. It is possible you may stuck at some point where you want explanation or help. Try searching on [SU], it will definitely help.

Comment: @Firelord plus I can connect to the Internet(albeit super slow). Anyway I took the phone home only to find out that she didn't put all the screws back in it, lol. So it falls apart, etc. It's really messed up. I should probably go exchange it in tomorrow, I just haven't found the time to get everything I need off of it. It'd probably blow up if I tried to install something on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24403/discussion-between-firelord-and-jmfb).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same promblem. A solution which worked for me was an app "[MP4Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smamolot.mp4fix)", which you can get in google play for free. It repaired my video in a few sec and placed it in different folder (it kept corrupted video in the same place and also created new repaired one). 
I know this info might be too late for you but it might help some others.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This answer might be more helpful if you add a link to the app you're recommending.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Martin's answer, yes you can use MP4Fix.  However it is very strict what the video is made with.
I found I needed to set the recording settings in order for the mp4 video to be in a supported format and not get error 'Not Supported'

Video Encoder H264
Recorder Format MPEG_4
File Format MP4
Audio Encoder AAC

Additionally I set video resolution, framerate, and bitrate.

I was then able to recover video.

FYI:  The Recording App is SVR but others are named the same.
Found using: secret video recorder (free) tristan
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tristan.enhanced_camera

Comment: You'd better disclose your relationship with that app.

Comment: My relationship with that app is end user.